# IPython Parallel programming dependencies

Tags: python, ipython, ipython-parallel

I am using iPython for some relatively heavy numerical tasks, subsets of which are more or less embarrassingly parallel. The tasks have very simple dependencies, but I'm struggling to work out the best way to implement them. The basic problem is that the result of a previous computation must be used in the following one, and I would like to submit those tasks to the engines separately.

Basically I've got

```
in0a = .... 
in0b = ....

res1a = f1(in0a)   ## expensive, would like to run on engine 0
res1b = f1(in0b)   ## expensive, would like to run on engine 1
### and same for c, d, ... on engines 2, 3, ... (mod the number of engines)

res2a = f2(res1a)  ### depends on res1a = f1(in0a) being computed
res2b = f2(res1b)  ### depends on res1b = f1(in0b) being computed
```

I could restructure things into some `f_12()` functions which call `f1` and `f2` in sequence, and return both outputs as a tuple (I'd like the main engine to have access to all the results) and just submit those asynchronously, or I could use a parallel map of `f1` on `[in0a, in0b, ...]` but I would strongly prefer not to do either of those refactorings.

So what I really want to know is how I can use `view.apply_async()` so that running `res2a=f2(res1a)` will only happen once `res1a=f1(in0a)` has run (and similarly for the b, c, d, ... tasks).

Basically, I want to use a blocking `apply_async`. With load-balancing it should be something like

```
res1a = v.apply_async(f1, in0a)
res2a = v.apply_async(f2, res1a)
```

But how do I make the second explicitly depend on the first? Do I need a `with v.temp_flags(follow=res1a)`? But then do I need to use `res1a.get()` in the call? Will that just block submission until it returns?

Or, how would I do this with a direct view? If I just submit all of the 'a' tasks to the same engine, but use `v.apply_async(f2, res1a.get())`, this blocks, and doesn't even get *submitted* until the `get()` returns.

Comment: Are you using a library for the futures?

Comment: @User: I don't understand the question. (This uses iPython's model for parallelism -- http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/parallel/index.html)

Comment: Have you tried to implement [dependencies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23290086/ipython-parallel-programming-dependencies)?

Comment: @Midnighter, yes using `with v.temp_flags(follow=res1a)`, but this doesn't work quite right because of the need for `res1a.get()` in the subsequent `v.apply_async`.